# How to Lock RectTransform's fields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating custom layout group and I want to control `RectTransform` on the child Objects. I want to lock some fields on child's `RectTransform` like when using canvas or Unity's Horizontal or Vertical group so that it cannot be modified.

I need the same effect. You can see this message on top of child's `RectTransform` : Some values driven by HorizontalLayoutGroup

[image]

I find a halfway :

Adding `[ExecuteInEditMode]` then:

```
public void Update()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    if (!Application.isPlaying)
    {
        /* Todo => update child's positions here. */
    }
#endif
}
```

Any other idea?

Comment: What do you mean by lock?

Comment: When we using `HorizontalLayoutGroup` we can't change child's position because it driven by layout group, and Editor's GUI feild's are locked from users to change. I need the same effect. you can see this message on top of child's RectTransform : `Some values driven by HorizontalLayoutGroup`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is done with the [`DrivenRectTransformTracker`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DrivenRectTransformTracker.html) API.

From the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DrivenRectTransformTracker.html):

> Driving a RectTransform means that the values of the driven
>   RectTransform are controlled by that component. These driven values
>   cannot be edited in the Inspector (they are shown as disabled). They
>   also won't be saved when saving a scene, which prevents undesired
>   scene file changes.
>
> Whenever the component is changing values of driven RectTransforms, it
>   should first call the Clear method and then use the Add method to add
>   all RectTransforms it is driving. The Clear method should also be
>   called in the OnDisable callback of the component.

No example from the doc but below is how to use it:

```
public RectTransform targetRC;
UnityEngine.Object driver;

void Start()
{
    DrivenRectTransformTracker dt = new DrivenRectTransformTracker();
    dt.Clear();

    //Object to drive the transform
    driver = this;
    dt.Add(driver, targetRC, DrivenTransformProperties.All);
}
```

The `RectTransform` linked to the `targetRC` variable will now be locked and cannot be modified from the Editor. It should now say something like *"Some values are driven by another object"*. You can use [`DrivenTransformProperties`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DrivenTransformProperties.html) to specify which variables to lock.

This is what it looks like after executing this code:

[image]

Comment: Thank, that was very helpful.

Comment: Note: this has never actually worked in Unity (in all versions since 2017) - it only drives *some* of the values (not all the ones it's supposed to - for instance: The anchor and size can't be controlled). I've been using it for years, and its highly frustrating.